# Semiconductor PN Polarity

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

When you apply voltage to the PN semiconductor and you achieve equilibrium, why is the N side still negative (-) and P side still positive (+) when considering that all of the ions have 4 valence electrons flowing around now.

Is it because of the difference in the number of protons that the acceptor ions and the donor ions have?

Comment: You refer to a PNP semiconductor. Do you mean a PN junction? Or do you really mean a PNP transistor in particular?

Comment: I meant a PN junction in a semiconductor.

Answer (score 1):

> When you apply voltage to the PN semiconductor and you achieve equilibrium, why is the N side still negative (-) and P side still positive (+)

I am not sure I completely understand what you are asking, but maybe this answer will help you to sharpen your question.

When a PN junction is in equilibrium, contrary to what one might expect, the P side has a net negative charge, and the N side has a net positive charge.

This happens through the following mechanism. On the N side, thermal energy produces free electrons and positively charged donor ions. Some of those free electrons diffuse, through random thermal motion, over to the P side. However, the donor ions stay where they are on the N side. Likewise on the P side thermal energy produces holes and negatively charged acceptor ions. Some of those holes diffuse, through random thermal motion, over to the N side. However, the negatively charged acceptor ions remain on the P side.

The result is that the P side has a surplus of both free electrons without corresponding donor ions, and acceptor ions without corresponding holes. So the P side will be **negatively** charged.  The N side, on the other hand has a surplus of holes without corresponding acceptor ions, and donor ions without corresponding free electrons. Thus, the N side will be **positively** charged.

This happens in a simple PN junction when it is in equilibrium, whether or not a bias is applied to the junction. If a forward bias is applied, electrons will flow into the N side, and out of the P side. This tends to reduce the surplus charges on each side of the junction. But while this is happening, more electrons diffuse from the N side to the P side, and more holes diffuse from the P side to the N side, and the net charges on each side, although they may get smaller, never go away entirely.

[The situation in a bipolar junction transistor is a little more complicated. The emitter-base junction, when it is unbiased, or forward biased, behaves just like described for the simple PN junction. However, in this case, the base has such a surplus of minority carriers (i.e. electrons in an NPN BJT, or holes in a PNP BJT) that many of these carriers diffuse over to the collector as well.]

Answer (score -1):

You can apply voltage in two ways, either in forward bias mode or reverse bias mode, if it is forward bias then the electrons in the n type get enough energy to cross the depletion region in the PN junction, and if you apply voltage in reverse bias mode electrons get pulled away from the depletion region making it impossible for them to cross we say the depletion region got widened.

I think you are not talking about these cases since you mentioned equilibrium which is achieved once the PN junction is formed before appling any voltage. If that is the case then the electrons in the N type get attracted by the holes in the P type and once the first electrons fill the first holes at the border between P and N, negative ions are formed in the P type at its border with N type and at the same time positive ions get formed (because electrons left) in the N type at its border with P type, and these stable ions that reached equilibrium by completing the number of electrons they need in their valence shell stop any further electrons movement because electrons coming from the N type to the P type will find the negative ions in the P type that will repel them.

And finally here's a passage from a book that can give a better explanation than mine.

[image: Extract from book: Beginner's Guide to Transistors by J. A. Reddihough]

Image source: "Beginner's Guide to Transistors" by *J. A. Reddihough*. Published for Newnes Books by The Hamlyn Publishing Group Ltd., 1968

Comment: oabdullae - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked for online material (for books etc. the title, author(s), publisher, edition and page number(s) should be included - a typical citation). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source details & added them for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: oh yeah I'm sorry I forgot to edit this as well when you told me in my question. Thanks for your editing. :)